# How to check whether isupper(cstr) worked?

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I'm simply trying to do an if statement and then report to the console that my character string is now uppercase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Stop";
    if (isupper(str) == "STOP")
    {
        std::cout << "str now == STR" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error that an integer cannot equal a const char*, which totally makes sense. Is my error that isupper is an integer statement? Sorry guys, I'm new to this. I looked around online but couldn't find anything for if statements checking isupper like this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: ..and it just returns non-zero. er

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will check until a lowercase letter is detected in the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "HELLO";
    bool flag = true; // for verification

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) // till string length
        if (!isupper(str[i])) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }

    if (flag) // verifies
        std::cout << "str is now STR" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "str is Not STR" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Remember, this won't make all the letter lowercase, as per of your requirement, it's just verifying and nothing else.

The `isupper()` converts a character into ASCII values and verifies whether it's existing between 65 to 90 or not. If not, then it's obviously not an uppercase letter. That's why it requires an integer.

Comment: The loop is off, even while whole idea is correct. You have to "short" it as soon as it finds difference

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie it's not clear what do you mean by "short", short what?

Comment: shorting the loop, literally. I.e. exiting it when critical check had failed.  If check for single character failed in this case, whole process have to flag a failure. In your case it does report success if last character was uppercase. When  it also return from current function, you have a case of short-circuit calculation of function as a whole

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie oh yes, thank you, that's added now. Hope that's what you were talking about.

Comment: Yes , as a variant..  but do `for ( auto i = 0, len = strlen(str); i < len`  you don't want your loop to be `O(n*n)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to check if a string is uppercase then you could do something like :

```
const bool allUpper = std::all_of(std::cbegin(str), std::cend(str) - 1, [] (unsigned char ch) {
    return std::isupper(ch);
});
```

If you want to make `str` uppercase then you could do :

```
std::transform(std::cbegin(str), std::cend(str) - 1, std::cbegin(str), [] (unsigned char ch) {
    return std::toupper(ch);
});
```

And if you want to compare `str` to `STOP` then you can simply use :

`const bool equivalent = std::strcmp(str, "STOP") == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/):
`isupper` function checks if parameter c is an uppercase alphabetic letter.

You are passing a char array to the function that receives an int.

You can create a utility function that checks for all uppercase of the string.

```
bool IsAllUpper(const char* str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (!isupper(str[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That function requires a loop of some kind to check every character. Possible solution

```
// assuming it's null-terminated string
bool IsUppercase(const char* str)
{
    // loop if character non-zero
    while(*str)
      // exit loop (and function) if return value is zero, increment pointer. 
      if(!isupper(*(str++))) return false;
    // we reached end of string.
    return true;
}
```

C++ offers better and safer ways to implement loop, e.g. range-based or container tools, but in case of naked C-string, C-style loop usually is most effective way.